# Bundling all python dependencies into a fatjar-like zip file

Tags: python

I have a python script that depends on `pycrypto`, `boto3` and `pyYaml`. I have to deliver this script to a client who is strictly non-technical and maynot even have access to the internet.

Is there a way to package everything up together so that the client can just extract the zip file and have the script working for him out of the box? Also, the script should be able to run on Windows/Mac/Linux and they can each have their own .zip files as well.

I have worked with `pip`, `requirements.txt` and `setuptools` in the past but have never done something very rudimentary like this. What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are deploying on Windows, [py2exe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe) will help you build a stand-alone executable. Look for the `-c` and `--bundle-files` options, which together will bundle files into a compressed archive with your executable.

If deploying to Mac, try [py2app](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app) instead.

In my experience, such bundlers are fussy, requiring at least some fiddling and experimentation. Some popular Python packages (e.g. PIL/Pillow, lxml, numpy, pandas, anything requiring a native C runtime) may have gotchas when mixed with bundler tools. So do *not* just bundle and deliver to a non-technical customer. Test and (if necessary) tweak before delivery.

This isn't a complete list of ways to install or deliver Python code. A few others [from vinta's awesome python list](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#distribution).